# How to create a high dimension tensor with fixed shape and dtype?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to return a tensor with fixed shape size, like, `torch.Size([1,345])`
However, when I input,

```
import torch
pt1 = torch.tensor(data=(1, 345), dtype=torch.int64)
```

it only return `torch.Size([2])`

I followed some tensor tutorial a tried to

```
pt1 = torch.tensor(1, 345, dtype=torch.int64)
pt1 = torch.tensor((1, 345), dtype=torch.int64)
pt1 = torch.tensor(shape=(1, 345), dtype=torch.int64)
```

It still shows error like `tensor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
I know some methods mean the data is (1,345) not shape, but...I am novice in pytorch and still not finding the solution of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` argument of [`torch.tensor`](https://html) is supposed to be *"Initial data for the tensor"* and not its shape.

All tensors have fixed shapes. You can define a tensor with uninitialized values with [`torch.empty`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html) or have them filled with specific values ([`torch.zeros`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.zeros.html), [`torch.ones`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ones.html), [`torch.full`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.full.html), ...). For instance:

```
>>> pt1 = torch.empty(1, 345, dtype=torch.int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use torch.zeros to make a new tensor

```py
import torch

a = torch.zeros((1,345), dtype=torch.int64)
print(a.shape)
```

```py
torch.Size([1, 345])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to pytorch's documentation about [torch.tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor.html#torch.tensor), your `torch.tensor(data=(1, 345), dtype=torch.int64)` code is creating a 2-element tensor [1, 345] ( so it has a size of [2]). To create a tensor like you want, use:

```
import torch

pt1 = torch.zeros((1, 345), dtype=torch.int64)
pt1.size()
# torch.Size([1, 345])
```